# Adding Cordova Plugin in iOS app in MAC System

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

In cordova iOS mobile app, while adding cordova 'privacyscreen' plugin into project directory, it says

```
Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:31:26
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/glob/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

I found similar solution, but not exactly.

I am trying to find the exact solution.

Please suggest.

Comment: current npm v 5.6.0 and node v 8.9.4

Comment: there are plenty of 'privacyscreen' plugins, can you specify the id and version?